# Find and replace of ArcGIS i got message "An invalid SQL statement was used"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table

I was replacing text in a field of attribute table, by using "Find and Replace".
After saving and making new map by [Layer properties--Categories--Unique values--VAlue field--add all values--ok]

Now when i tried to replace some text values as before i am getting this msg

*"An invalid SQL statement was used"* {i am attaching screenshot}[image]

Please help, i want to replace some text like "Calcareous duricrust" with "{Calcareous Duricrust}"

What can i do?

Comment: Not exactly sure what's going wrong for you, but a workaround seems to be to use Select by attributes --> Select all with the incorrect attribute --> Use Field Calculator to change it.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, I would use the field calculator (example with python syntax below)

```
"{" + !UNIT_NAME!.title() + "}"
```

.title() will capitalize the first letter of each word, and the + sign is used for concatenation. As mentioned by @Martin, you can use select by attribute first if you don't want to apply this rule to all your records.

Alternatively, you can use the .replace() function on a case by case basis (no need to select)

```
"{" + !UNIT_NAME!.replace("duricrust","Duricrust") + "}"
```

Comment: Good answer, although I have used find and replace in ArcMap attribute tables many times and it works just fine.

Comment: @cl3 I've removed the first line. Thank you for your comment.